# English to German Dictionary for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, software-rec, dictionary, translation

Is there any free application which give this functionality? I have seen this,

http://www.tekl.de/english/Dictionary_Plugins.HTML,

which is great, but I need something which can help me in English to German translation.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/)?

They also have a desktop widget [here](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/travel/translate_jeroenwielandt.html), although I've never used it.

Comment: That is good but i was looking for something which dont require internet connection, any how it is good solution.